# accessing data from static class function to my statefulwidget always returns null

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I do have a static class function wherein I fetch my data from my cloud firestore.
the structure of my cloudfire store that I am fetching is something like this.

```
collection("users")
 -documentId("userUid")
  -documentField("userUniqueHandle") // <- this is what I am trying to access
```

and here is my static class function.

```
class FetchUniqueHanlder {
  static final FirebaseFirestore _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  static String? myData; // Static variable to store the data

  static Stream<String?> fetchDataStream() {
    return _firestore.collection("users").doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid).snapshots().map((snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.exists) {
        myData = snapshot.get('userUniqueHandle'); // Store the data in myData
        return myData;
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    });
  }
}
```

and in my StatefulWidget called `ProfilePage.dart` I do have `initState` wherein I call the static class function to access the return data, however it always returns null to me.

`ProfilePage.dart`

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    FetchUniqueHanlder.fetchDataStream(); // Start fetching data from Firestore
    String? myData = FetchUniqueHanlder.myData; // Access myData
    print('myData in initState: $myData'); // <- whenever I am trying to print the access data from static class function it always returns null.
  }
```

Comment: `fetchDataStream` sets `myData` asynchronously.  You must have something that waits for `fetchDataStream`'s returned `Stream` to fire an event, and you cannot do that from `initState`.  Use a [`StreamBuilder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StreamBuilder-class.html).